# Scheduling coroutines with asyncio in Python

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have the following code which scrapes a web table with 1000 lines and 10 columns.
I have successfully generated a dataframe using nested for loops, but it takes well over three minutes.
In a (futile) attempt to save time, I have ventured into asyncio, watched several videos, andread many tutorials. I can't seem to figure out a structure which will make this work. Everything online is ultra simplistic and not terribly explicit.
Currently I get an error that a future is asked for without an await on the line creating the data frame.

What am I missing to get the rows and cells asyncronously?

```
# Wait on the table to load so we know all the data is there.
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//table/tbody')))

# Determine the number of rows and columns
rows = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//table/tbody/tr')
cols = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//table/tbody/tr[1]/td')

# use a list comprehension for each row and gather all the rows
result = asyncio.create_task(startgathering(driver, len(cols), len(rows)))
names = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F','G', 'H', 'I']
df = pd.DataFrame(result, columns=names)  # Error occurs here
driver.quit()


async def startgathering(driver, ncols, nrows):
    result = await asyncio.gather(*[getrows(driver, i, ncols) for i in range(1, nrows)])
    return result


async def getrows(driver, i, ncols):
    lrow = await asyncio.gather(*[driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f'//table/tbody/tr[{i}]/td[{j}]')
                .text for j in range(1, ncols)])
    return lrow
```

Comment: You're mixing synchronous and asynchronous code deliberately - so it won't work. What is the URL and what information do you want to get?

Comment: You need to understand that asyncio improves performance only in the cases where IO-bound operations are the bottleneck—i.e. downloading webpages, reading files, etc.  In your case, the bottlenecks are string processing operations, which are CPU-bound. So you should be optimizing the way to parse the string or resort to multiprocessing, instead of trying asyncio.

Comment: @AndrejKesely,  I can't give the website because it is a work site that is local access only. I apologize.

Comment: @MostafaFarzán, this routine is making 10,000 calls to the website which occur at about 50-60 per second. Strings only take a milisecond or so. I cannot just grab the string because it has random cells dispursed throughout with no data, and there are several different tables which all have different empty cells. Thus, any combination of regex, csv formatting, etc. I have tried work with one table and fail on the others. Setting up dozens of cases which are tailored to one table each isn't the best way to handle the code because the tables have new data appended regularly.